# how to put JSON nested array in a dependant select list in React

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, web

Sorry for my English, I'm also new to React
I'm using react-select
I want to make it so the first select box shows college names and the second select box shows the departments inside the college selected on the previous select

this is the JSON file

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "college_ar": "الحاسب الآلي ونظم المعلومات",
        "departments": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "department_ar": "علوم الحاسب الآلي",
                "college_id": 1,
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "department_ar": "هندسة الحاسب الآلي",
                "college_id": 1,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "college_ar": "إدارة الأعمال",
        "departments": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "department_ar": "إدارة الأعمال",
                "college_id": 2,
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "department_ar": "التسويق",
                "college_id": 2,

            }
         ]
    }
]
```

my code which kinda works though when I select the college it displays all the departments in one option\cell I understand why it does that as im giving the whole array as one input to the label, but I can't figure out how to do it otherwise :(

```
const college_name = this.state.colleges.map((college) => {
      return {
        value: college.id,
        label: college.college_ar,
      };
    });

    const departments_name = this.state.colleges.map((college) => {
      return {
        value: college.departments.map((department)=> {return department.id;}),
        label: college.departments.map((department)=> {return department.department_ar;}),
        link:  college.id,
      };
    });
```

the select code:

```
<Select
     label="Single select"
     value={this.state.selectedOption.value}
     onChange={this.handleChange1}
     options={college_name}
     styles={styles}/>

<Select
     name="Single select"
     value={this.state.selectedOption2.value}
     onChange={this.handleChange2}
     options={filteredOptions}
     styles={styles}/>
```

Comment: Would you mind to put the exact code you are using, I don't see any problem with the link you posted

Comment: the link is the reference i based my code on, tho the link is static input, where my code takes the input from an API that returns JSON files

Comment: I would use a ternary operator in the select values to match whatever you are trying to do. Put your code in sandbox and let's work on it.